# How to access and manipulate size classes in code for iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, size

There's a decent amount of information online about using size classes in XCode for iOS 8, but little or nothing about reading, interpreting, or manipulating size classes in code.  Is doing so in code even an option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course, once again I find what I've been looking for after(!) I post on SO :)

In iOS 8, there is in fact a class `UITraitCollection` that has information about size class.

To get access to it when it changes, any `UIViewController` can override methods of either of 2 protocols that `UIViewController` implements:

`UIContentContainer - viewWillTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:`

`UITraitEnvironment - traitCollectionDidChange:`

Even easier, `self.traitCollection` can be accessed within any `UIViewController`.